# Python selenium does not return the correct element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am new in selenium.

I want to run the automation test for calendar with python selenium, but the return does not same as my expect

The website for testing: https://letcode.in/calendar

I want to select the date in the right calendar.
[the right calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC6ZB.png)

So I create the variable for the right calendar:
`calendarInside = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-root/app-calender/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]")`

But when I filter all elements inside the `calendarInside` with
`allDays = calendarInside.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datepicker-date is-current-month']")`
the return will include the elements from the left calendar.

How can I select and filter only the element in the right calendar?

The result show in both 2 calendars like image
[Result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6htp.png)

The selenium version: selenium 4.9.1
Full code demo, you can run it to see the problem:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def testCalendar():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get("https://letcode.in/calendar")
    calendarInside = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-root/app-calender/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]")
    calendarInside.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "datetimepicker-clear-button").click()
    calendarInside.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".datetimepicker-dummy-input.is-datetimepicker-range").click()
    dayExpected = [6, 25]
    allDays = calendarInside.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datepicker-date is-current-month']")
    for dayfrom in allDays:
        print("dayfrom: " + str(dayfrom.text) + " - expected: " + str(dayExpected[0]))
        if str(dayfrom.text) == str(dayExpected[0]):
            dayfrom.click()
            break
    time.sleep(2)
    
    allDays = calendarInside.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datepicker-date is-current-month']")
    for dayto in allDays:
        print("dayto: " + str(dayto.text) + " - expected: " + str(dayExpected[1]))
        if str(dayto.text) == str(dayExpected[1]):
            dayto.click()
            break
    
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()

def main():
    testCalendar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I select and filter only the element in the right calendar?
Could you give me some idea for that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist`.

Allow me to simplify your code by unlocking the power of XPath conditions to find elements in the DOM.

```py
from browserist import Browser

RIGHT_CALENDAR_XPATH = "/html/body/app-root/app-calender/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/nwb-date-picker"

def open_calendar(browser: Browser) -> None:
    browser.click.button(f"{RIGHT_CALENDAR_XPATH}/div[2]/div[1]/div/input[1]")

def select_date_in_open_calendar(date: int, browser: Browser) -> None:
    browser.click.button(f"{RIGHT_CALENDAR_XPATH}//div[contains(@class, 'datepicker-date is-current-month')]/button[contains(text(), '{date}')]")

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://letcode.in/calendar")
    open_calendar(browser)
    select_date_in_open_calendar(5, browser)
    select_date_in_open_calendar(26, browser)
```

Notes:

- You can use [XPath with functions and conditions](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html). First, I search for dates with the `is-current-month` class – to avoid conflicts of multiple fields with the same date, e.g. 1 or 30, from respectively previous or next month.
- Then I pick the child element that contains the relevant date number with, for instance, `/button[contains(text(), '5')]`.
- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) doesn't need explicit conditions like `expected_conditions`, `WebDriverWait`, or `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` – it's already built in so you don't have to worry about it. Instead, [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) awaits an element to be fully loaded before it interacts with it. More on this concept [here](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/#difference-from-selenium).

Here's what I get (slowed down as [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) finishes the job almost in a blink of an eye). I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have questions?

[image: Screen capture of Browserist in action]

Answer (score -1):

try updated code below, your locators were not correct the locatos you have added were for the first date picker

Also this click should be done before to show the datepicker not after

```
calendarInside.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".datetimepicker-dummy-input.is-datetimepicker-range").click()
```

Full code

```
   import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def testCalendar():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get("https://letcode.in/calendar")
    rangeInput = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".datetimepicker-dummy-input.is-datetimepicker-range")
    rangeInput.click()
    calendarInside = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                         '//div[contains(@class,"datetimepicker")  and contains(@class,'
                                         '"is-datetimepicker-default")]')
    calendarInside.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Clear"]').click()
    dayExpected = [6, 25]

    allDays = calendarInside.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                           "//div[@class='datepicker is-active']//div[@class='datepicker-date is-current-month']//button")
    for dayfrom in allDays:
        print("dayfrom: " + str(dayfrom.text) + " - expected: " + str(dayExpected[0]))
        if str(dayfrom.text) == str(dayExpected[0]):
            dayfrom.click()
            break
    time.sleep(2)

    allDays = calendarInside.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datepicker is-active']//div[@class='datepicker-date is-current-month']//button")
    for dayto in allDays:
        print("dayto: " + str(dayto.text) + " - expected: " + str(dayExpected[1]))
        if str(dayto.text) == str(dayExpected[1]):
            dayto.click()
            break

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()


def main():
    testCalendar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, but it still not corrects. Your result same with me. You can check in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6htp.png

Comment: I didn't check that clicking calendar part, i thought you wanted correct locator for calendar only, try updated code now, should select values in calendar now

Comment: Thanks, the comment from Abhay works, but I still do not understand the root cause ;D

Comment: your locators were not correct, try using some extension like this [Xpath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) it will highlight the elements that are being selected by your Xpath , will make element identifications little easier

Answer (score -1):

you may try this way:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

def testCalendar():

    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    driver = Chrome(options=options)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://letcode.in/calendar")

    right_calendar = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="column"]')))[1]

    right_calendar.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.datetimepicker-clear-button').click()
    right_calendar.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.datetimepicker-dummy-input.is-datetimepicker-range').click()

    dayExpected = [6, 25]

    allDays = right_calendar.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.datepicker-date.is-current-month')

    for dayfrom in allDays:
        print("dayfrom: " + str(dayfrom.text) + " - expected: " + str(dayExpected[0]))
        if dayfrom.text == str(dayExpected[0]):
            dayfrom.click()
            break
    time.sleep(1)

    allDays = right_calendar.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.datepicker-date.is-current-month')
    for dayto in allDays:
        print("dayto: " + str(dayto.text) + " - expected: " + str(dayExpected[1]))
        if dayto.text == str(dayExpected[1]):
            dayto.click()
            break

    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testCalendar()
```

output:

```py
dayfrom: 1 - expected: 6
dayfrom: 2 - expected: 6
dayfrom: 3 - expected: 6
dayfrom: 4 - expected: 6
dayfrom: 5 - expected: 6
dayfrom: 6 - expected: 6
dayto: 1 - expected: 25
dayto: 2 - expected: 25
dayto: 3 - expected: 25
dayto: 4 - expected: 25
dayto: 5 - expected: 25
dayto: 6 - expected: 25
dayto: 7 - expected: 25
dayto: 8 - expected: 25
dayto: 9 - expected: 25
dayto: 10 - expected: 25
dayto: 11 - expected: 25
dayto: 12 - expected: 25
dayto: 13 - expected: 25
dayto: 14 - expected: 25
dayto: 15 - expected: 25
dayto: 16 - expected: 25
dayto: 17 - expected: 25
dayto: 18 - expected: 25
dayto: 19 - expected: 25
dayto: 20 - expected: 25
dayto: 21 - expected: 25
dayto: 22 - expected: 25
dayto: 23 - expected: 25
dayto: 24 - expected: 25
dayto: 25 - expected: 25
```

**[UPDATE]**:

There is not much difference between your code and my code. The only difference is in the line where you define the variable `allDays`.

I used a `CSS_SELECTOR` while you've used the `XPATH`. And if you want to use only the `XPATH`, please refer to the explanation below.

Few notes on your code to make it work as expected:

1. Your code absolutely works fine without any issue but the reason it's picking the dates from both the right and left calendars is because of the XPATH you're using.
2. To fix this so that it only picks the date from within the desired element (`calendarInside` in your case),

   use:

   `calendarInside.find_elements(By.XPATH, "*//div[@class='datepicker-date is-current-month']")`

   instead of:

   `calendarInside.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datepicker-date is-current-month']")`
3. If you notice the difference is only of a `*` which makes the given XPATH a child of the element(`calendarInside` here).

So, you just need to put a `*` in the XPATH of the variable `allDays` in your code as explained above and it starts picking the dates only from your desired (right) calendar.

The **asterisk (*)**: Selects all element nodes in the current context.
[reference](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt-2nd-edition/9780596527211/ch03s02s05.html#:%7E:text=XPath%20features%20three%20wildcards%3A,namespace%20prefix%20with%20an%20asterisk.)

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Wow, just change find the element from Xpath to CSS, and everything works as expected. Do you know what is the root cause/ ;D

Comment: I've added the explanation above.

Comment: Wow, I do not know about this Wildcards. I couldn’t have done it without you, many thanks. I try the other way with XPATH, and it works "driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='columns']/div[2]//button[@class='date-item']")", but I still want to use the parent to filter like your recommend.